# How to get back to the original state in redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have to actions `FETCH_REPOS` and `FILTER_BY_LANGUAGE`. When the app runs, the repos are fetched from the server and loaded in the store.

Then I try to filter by language

```
case 'FILTER_BY_LANGUAGE':
  let newState =  { 
    repos:[...new Set(state.repos)]
         .filter(val => val.language == action.payload)
    }
    return newState
```

The scenario is, I fetch 30 repositories. Say 10 are JS, 10 PHP and 10 Node.

I then filter the JS repos. Now the store has 10 repos instead of 20, so when I try to filter again my PHP, those repos are go.

Show are refetch the data again or should I filter the data within the react props?

Here are the actions

```
export const fetchRepos = () => dispatch => {
    fetch('http://localhost:4000/originalrepos')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(repos => {
            let content = repos.map((data, i)=>{
                return {
                    title: data.name,
                    username: data.owner.login,
                    avatar: data.owner.avatar_url,
                    date: data.updated_at,
                }
            })
            dispatch({
                type: 'FETCH_REPOS',
                payload: content
            })
        })
}
export const filterByLanguage = language => dispatch => {
    dispatch({
        type: 'FILTER_BY_LANGUAGE',
        payload: language

    })
}
```

I `fetchRepos` on mount, then the `FILTER_BY_LANGUAGE` sort of reduces the store. **An expected behaviour**, so I'm wondering whether I need to run the same fetch within `FILTER_BY_LANGUAGE` or remove that action all together and take care of filtering the store at the props? Thought these are the reasons to use redux, right?

Comment: Share another part of the code.

Comment: @DenysKotsur just added more code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save your state whenever there's a state change with something like this:

```
var stateHistory = []

YourReducer = (state, action){

  //Whenever the reducer is called, it pushes to the history
  stateHistory.push(state)

  switch(action.type){
    ...
    case "UNDO":
      //fire the UNDO action to go back to the last recorded state
      return stateHistory.pop()
  }
}
```

You might want to check if the new state is the same as the last pushed state before adding it to the history object.

Comment: BTW here's a redux article about implementing state undo history: https://redux.js.org/recipes/implementingundohistory

Answer (score 1):

You should not replace your repos from redux store. Instead, you can add a filter to get visible repos, so all repos are still in your store, but you can choose the one you want to see. You can check redux todo list as example.

```
const getVisibleRepos = (repos, filter) => {
  switch (filter) {
    case VisibilityFilters.SHOW_ALL:
      return repos
    case VisibilityFilters.SHOW_PHP:
      return repos.filter(t => t.type === 'node')
    case VisibilityFilters.SHOW_NODE:
      return repos.filter(t => t.type === 'php')
    default:
      return repos;
  }
}
​
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  todos: getVisibleRepos(state.repos, state.visibilityFilter)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter the repos only in the client side, you should maintain all repos in the state always, and filter them in another property like `filteredRepos`

Answer (score 0):

I do not think we can revert redux state changes. One of the solution could be to maintain two lists in the state. One original and one filtered so that you will always have the original list handy and the filtered list could have filtered items.

```
case 'FETCH_REPOS':
    return { repos: action.payload };

case 'FILTER_BY_LANGUAGE':
    let newState = { 
        filteredRepos: [...new Set(state.repos)].filter(val => val.language == action.payload)
    }
    return newState;
```